# Angular Javascript Array of Object from a ReplaySubject

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object

I'm new on Angular. I tried to make an array of object from a ReplaySubject.

Here I have an array of ReplaySubject and i do a looping and subscribe the data inside of it and push into an array variable.

```
var combine_data = [];
this.productService.getLot(product_ids.join('-')).forEach(function(data){
    data.subscribe(v => {
        combine_data.push(v);
    });
});
```

the result when I console.log on it will become like this
[image]

I tried to do a `combine_data.find(data => data.id === 92);` and its return undefined.

And I tried to make a dummy array of object using simple for iteration

```
var test = [];
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    test.push({id:i,name:'name'});
}
```

and the result of this dummy array when I console.log on it become quite different with previous one
[image]

By using this dummy array, I got a `(4)[{..}{..}{..}{..}` and I can do a `.find` on it, but using the first array, I got a `[]` and I cannot do a `.find` on it.

Here's the result of `this.productService.getLot(product_ids.join('-'))`
[image]

And here's the function of productService.getLot

```
public getLot(id: string){
    var _this = this;

    var result = [];
    var ids = [];
    ids = id.split('-');
    ids.forEach(function(product_id){
        if (_this.products[product_id] == null) {
            _this.products[product_id] = new ReplaySubject<any>();
            _this.http.get(`https://xxxx.com/api/products/${product_id}`)
                .subscribe(data => {
                    _this.products[product_id].next(data)
                });
        }

        result.push(_this.products[product_id]);
    });

    return result;
}
```

Its the same method push a data into a variable. But why I got a different result? I really don't understand.

I just make a stackblitz for my case problem
[HttpClientCombineData](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-httpclient-combinedata)

Comment: What does `this.productService.getLot(product_ids.join('-'))` return?

Comment: may be you are trying `.find()` before the data is pushed to the array. Do a check like `if(this.combineData.length)  this.combineData.find(... );`

Comment: @KurtHamilton its a array of ReplaySubject. I'm using this ReplaySubject to caching the data that I got from the httpClient API from my server. I make it seperate per-product, so in the future I can access product seperately. I just updated my post for the result of getLot and the function of getLot. Thanks

Comment: @xuweisen : Ok, there is some really bad code here. Can you let me know the reason to push so many `ReplaySubjects` ? Also, you should use `forkJoin` rather than using `http` in `for` loop.  Let me know your actual intention of using `ReplaySubject`, I think I am missing something. I would like to suggest accordingly :)   cheers !

Comment: Where is this line- combine_data.find(data => data.id === 92); ? Inside subcribe() or outside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are starting with an array of product ids, joining them into a `-` separated string, and then in the service you are splitting that string and building an array of `ReplaySubject`, which you then emit the response of an http request into.

Assuming that you want to run your http requests in parallel, you would be far better simplifying this by using `forkJoin`. `forkJoin` combines multiple observables into one set of parallel observables, and returns a value when they all complete.

component.ts

```js
this.productService.getLot(product_ids).subscribe(combine_data => {
  console.log(combine_data); // [ {...}, {...}, ... ]
});
```

service.ts

```js
public getLot(productIds: []): Observable<[]> {
  // create array of observable requests
  // these are only invoked when the component subscribes to this observable

  const observables = productIds.map(productId => 
    _this.http.get(`https://xxxx.com/api/products/${productId}`));

  return forkJoin(observables);
}
```

Comment: I tried forkJoin before, but I got lost too deep on the Observable<[]> thats why I tried to make it loop that makes me easier to understand. But I know my code is really bad in here. let me try to understand more about forkJoin. Thank you very much for your suggestion. I edited my post by adding the stackblitz for my case problem. Thanks

Comment: I would say `forkJoin` is far easier to understand than what you were doing. `forkJoin` simply takes a set (array in this case) of observables, executes them when `subscribe` is called, and then returns the corresponding array of responses to the callback in `subscribe.

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation, I think I need learn about the Observable and RsJx. I just move from developing php and now trying to learn more about Angular, and its quite feel jetlag for it.

Thank you very much